# Can Google Analytics track the profile of website visitors?

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, visitor-statistic

I read this reference https://www.codehousegroup.com/insight-and-inspiration/digital-strategy/sitecore-analytics-vs-google-analytics

There said that Google Analytics cannot track visitor profiles

Is it true?

I have installed Google Analytics on my website. I want to analyze the user's profile data that has been logged. How do I do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to track userId, an hash of your user's crm id or his email that you know when the user is logged: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

You can track it as custom dimension too at user level.

Comment: So actually Google Analytics can track visitor profiles? It can tracks profile and engagement value. It can help I track visitor behaviour, so I can understand their actions and their potential interests. Right?

Comment: Yes,  it depends what you track, and how you track it. With Analytics you can track user navigation. You can match then userid with id of your crm.

Comment: Okay. But Why this article https://www.codehousegroup.com/insight-and-inspiration/digital-strategy/sitecore-analytics-vs-google-analytics says sitecore analytics has sitecore profiles, engagement values, and personalization? As if sitecore analytics are better than google analytics

Comment: @MartenCatcher: solution is yet included: "You have to track userId, an hash of your user's crm id or his email that you know when the user is logged". It is already the second time in 2 days that make this type of report. You should know the topic before making certain reports.

Comment: I am still confused how to send a user id or email to Google Analytics. I'm afraid my google account will be deleted

Comment: Google has a minimum hashing requirement of SHA256 and strongly recommends the use of a salt, with a minimum of 8 characters: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Comment: Okay thanks I will study it first